# left join, inner join, one before the other, other issue?

Tags: mysql

I have a form and MySQL that works with this:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT p.*
         , t.*, f.name AS fname 
      FROM table_posts p
      JOIN table_topics t 
      USING(tid)
      JOIN table_forums f 
        ON f.fid = t.fid
     WHERE f.fid IN($forums)";
```

I wish to add an option on the form so that any tid's in the subscriptions table for the user are excluded from the results from the sql above:

```
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN (SELECT x.tid FROM table_subscriptions AS x WHERE x.username = '$user' AND x.type = 'x' GROUP BY x.tid) AS query2 USING (tid) AND query2.tid IS NULL";
```

however, am encountering 
MySQL encountered the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN (

Is the issue because the left join should be done first, or is there some other issue? Any clues for corrections appreciated.

Comment: joins are part of the from clause that precedes the where clause. You got the syntax error because you placed the left join into the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring in the subscriptions table with a `LEFT JOIN`, and then filter on unmatched records in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT 
    p.*, 
    t.*, 
    f.name AS fname
FROM table_posts AS p 
INNER JOIN table_topics AS t USING (tid) 
INNER JOIN table_forums AS f ON f.fid = t.fid
LEFT JOIN table_subscriptions AS s ON s.username = ? AND s.type = 'x' AND s.tid = p.tid
WHERE 
    f.fid IN (?, ?, ?)
    AND s.tid IS NULL
```

Note: I updated your query so it uses query parameters instead of concatenating variables in the SQL string: this is both more efficient and secure.

You can also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
    p.*, 
    t.*, 
    f.name AS fname "
FROM table_posts AS p 
INNER JOIN table_topics AS t USING (tid) 
INNER JOIN table_forums AS f ON f.fid = t.fid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_subscriptions AS s
    WHERE s.username = ? AND s.type = 'x' AND s.tid = p.tid
)
WHERE f.fid IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Should the second example be
AND f.fid IN (?, ?, ?)